# Read DB records with Linq and show on DataGrid by foreign key

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-6

I have two Classes: `Factor` and `FactorItems`. I also have three Windows: `Win1`, `Win2`, `WinRead`. `Win1` contains a DataGrid named `grd1`; `Win2` contains a DataGrid named `grdItems` and `WinRead` contains a DataGrid named `grdRead`.

There is a foreign key from `Factor` on `FactorItems`.
I used `SaveChanges()` method and inserting data to both table from `Win2` `grdItems`. In addition, I can read and show `Factor's` table records in `grd1` and all thing are correct.

Now I want when I click (I used `DataGridCellChanges`) on a `grd1` row (for example, with `Id == 50`), it should load `WinRead` and show all `FactorItems` with their foreign key that was `Factor_Id 50` on `WinRead_Load` grdRead.

**Factor**

```
public class Factor
{
    public Factor()
    {
        this.BuyList = new List<FactorItems>();
    }

    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FactorItems> BuyList { get; set; }
}
```

**FactorItems**

```
public class FactorItems
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName `enter code here`{ get; set; }
    public int NumberInBox { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Factor Factors{ get; set; }
}
```

**Win1**

```
private void grd1_SelectedCellsChanged(objectsender,SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    WinRead wread = new WinRead
    if (grd1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        wread.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**WinRead**

```
private void grdRead_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var ctx = new EntContext())
    {
        //What do I write here?
    }
}
```

Comment: where are u facing the problem ? in reading the data or displaying on UI?

Comment: @AvinashReddy On both i have problem.

Comment: Try to add some code for the qustion

Comment: @AvinashReddy Please check i edited.

Comment: Database " var records=ctx.Factor.BuyList.where(x=>x.Id==50).Tolist();"

Comment: NameofDataGrid.Itemsource=records;

Comment: Thank you it is work for me but not finally answer and my purpose. I want when grd1 clicked the Factor Id passed to Win2 and i show items on grdItems like `x=>x.Id == Factor_Id` @AvinashReddy

Comment: Means its working fine right?

Comment: passed by Foreign key what do u mean?

Comment: I remove my last comment. See i explained all in title and body. my issue is when user click on any row on grd1 in win1 it must load all items Win3 and grdItems. here Factor_Id is forigen , infact it is a row on grd1. Did you get?

Comment: You mean my Issue exactly. now my problem is just how to set Selecteditemsforigenkey. @AvinashReddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Factor row = dataGridPrincipal.SelectedItem as Factor;
```

Now u will have the selected object

```
WinRead wread = new WinRead
if (grd1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    wread.grid.itemsource= ctx.Factor.BuyList.where(x=>x.Id==row.forignkey).Tolist()
    wread.ShowDialog(); 
}
```

**Or**

create prop in `WinRead` and save the foreign key there  and in load event, u can load

Comment: Thank you, By creating Prop in `WinRead` i done it.

Comment: that will be fine too.anytime.